# Parse file for maximum value

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse some data contained within a file:

```
>in:12 out:8 John

>in:20 out:12 Fred

>in:8 out:2 Danny
```

I would like to find the maximum `in` value, and find who has the maximum `in` (Fred does in my example).

Comment: Does this need to use regular expressions? There are much easier ways to parse this data.

Comment: i got no idea, i thought i can try to do it with regex.

Comment: Regular expressions are the wrong tool for the job. The two answers currently supplied explain why.

Comment: i got some difficulty to understand the answer but i ll try that thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a non-standard data format you've got there. Hence, you've to write a non-standard parser (a better idea would be to use a standard exchange format like JSON and use a parser from the standard library). I'd

- create a `Person` class with, say, an `in` and `out` attribute
- write a parser function that takes a line from the input file and, if the line contains valid data, creates a new `Person`
- create a list of `Person`s from your input file called `persons`.
- sort this list ascending by `in`: `persons_sorted = sorted(persons, key=lambda p: p.in)`
- get the maximum: `max_in_person = persons_sorted[-1]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
>in:(\d+) out:\d+ (.*)
```

Group 1 will contain the in score and group 2 the name

You'll still have to filter the maximum of group 1 in python code to get the name as this is not what regexes are for.

I'm not a python programmer but this is a good start

```
for match in re.finditer(r">in:(\d+) out:\d+ (.*)", subject):
# match start: match.start()
# match end (exclusive): match.end()
# matched text: match.group()
```